# How OpenGL (ES) stores textures/vertexes

Tags: opengl-es

I'm intrested in OpenGL ES storage mechanism. Does it copy any data to it's own memory or does it just store pointer to data. If no coping is done (what is logical), than why VBO's are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key thing is to remember that OpenGL(ES) is build as a client-server model... that means that usually the "CPU" is a client and the "GPU" is a server.

Those two have different memory storage. When you want to draw some vertices you need to send it from "CPU" to "GPU" this usually involves copying data from system memory to GPU memory.
Each frame you need to send it over and over to perform drawing... it is of course slow.

VBOs are the way to store those vertex data on the GPU and then simply avoid copying... just add a command "Draw" and the data will be fetched not from system memory but from GPU memory. That will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed. Does it applies to textures too? Everytime i draw binded texture it's copied to gpu?

Comment: the texture is sent to GPU in glTexImage* or glCopyTexImage... style functions. So textures are similar to VBOS... but VBOS are a bit general in its usage. If you look at CUDA/OpenCL then you will notice that GPU becomes more and more generic and they give full access to memory pool... its up to the user to use it in custom way.

Comment: @fen As a side remark, since `glCopyTexImage` takes the texture image from the framebuffer, it shouldn't incur a CPU-GPU copy.

Comment: right! glTexImage* and glTexSubImage copy data from CPU to GPU, glCopyTexImage stores the framebuffer data in the texture...

Answer (score 0):

Textures and buffer objects ultimately have no relation to one another. No direct relationship at any rate.

However, they do have some similarities. They both represent memory allocated by OpenGL. Therefore, any data uploading to them is a *copy* operation. Even textures.